google-chrome-stable is already the newest version? (but it is not)
I already checked several answers here but none really answers my question. If I already have the latest version, what must I do to get rid of it and reintstall Chrome so it does not appear anymore?
I saw an answer about installing Chromium from the store but I don't think it has the latest Chrome updates.

This question is similar to: How to install Google Chrome. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Found my anwser : you don't need to go to the new "App center" but to "Software and Updates" where the google-chrome-stable is unticked by defautl ! Yo need to select it, then request for the update.
